# Cannot decrypt partition with TWRP

Tags: twrp, lineageos

I have a S9 with LineageOS on it and I cannot mount the data using TWRP. I had MobileIron on it but uninstalled that as it started crashing. I'm not sure if the two are related or if there is something else up..